# MYSQL SELECT with INNER JOIN and LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I'm not very familiar with MYSQL and stuck.

How can I add a `LIMIT 0,100` to the following query:

```
SELECT 
    m.meta_id, 
    m.meta_key, 
    m.meta_value, 
    m.post_id, 
    p.post_title, 
    p.post_parent, 
    p.post_status
FROM 
    wp_abcd_postmeta m
    INNER JOIN wp_abcd_posts as p 
        ON( 
            p.id = m.post_id 
            AND p.post_type = 'product_variation'
        )
```

Expected result would be to get an array with 100 items. I tried adding it to the end but this only results in 4 items (I guess because the inner join filter is executed later)

If I run the query with `LIMIT 100` at the end I get 4 results - without I get more than 500...

If I run the query with `LIMIT 100` and `ORDER BY m.post_id` I get again only a few results but not 100 so to me it seems like the limit here is not quite working...

Comment: Some have suggested LIMIT. Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. But for further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: How exactly does this help in answering my question?

Comment: It means your question is less likely to be closed, which may prove helpful.

Comment: helpful would be to ask for missing information or clarification instead...

Comment: The accepted answer covers all of that.

Comment: ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
    m.meta_id, 
    m.meta_key, 
    m.meta_value, 
    m.post_id, 
    p.post_title, 
    p.post_parent, 
    p.post_status
FROM 
    wp_abcd_postmeta m
    INNER JOIN wp_abcd_posts as p 
        ON p.id = m.post_id 
        AND p.post_type = 'product_variation'
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure u have data in both the table,if now than you may use **left** or **right** join depending on your table data.

Than try this query

```
SELECT m.meta_id, m.meta_key, m.meta_value, m.post_id, p.post_title, p.post_parent,p.post_status FROM wp_abcd_postmeta m INNER JOIN wp_abcd_posts as p on p.id = m.post_id and p.post_type = 'product_variation' limit 100
```